# Pie chart labels do not render properly

Tags: plotting, manipulate, visualization, charts, style

I am working on a project and this pie chart needs to have same-sized labels that emanate "radially" outward. There will be concentric charts outside this core with more information about the categories. Let's consider an example with fruits where all sectors occupy the chart space identically (i.e. categories are alike and subcategories to be charted later will retain a similar structure radiating outward).

```
fruits = {"Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Dates", "Eggfruit",  "Fig"};
pie01 = ConstantArray[1, Length@fruits];
PieChart[pie01, ChartLabels -> fruits, LabelingSize -> 70]
```

[image: a pie chart with equal sectors]

After many attempts at trying to understand how the text is rendered amidst the underlying interactions, I placed the code inside a Manipulate block. (ToUpperCase was just my attempt to check if this had any effect on the rendering but it doesn't change the outcome substantially)

```
Manipulate[
 PieChart[pie01,
  ImageSize -> 350,
  LabelingSize -> lbsz, 
  ChartLabels -> 
   Placed[ToUpperCase[fruits], (*list req. here *)
    "RadialCenter", 
    Style[Rotate[#, r Degree], fsize, Black] &
    ]
  ],
 {{r, 0, "\[Degree] rotated"}, 0, 360, 5},
 {{lbsz, 10, "LabelingSize"}, 5, 80, 5},
 {{fsize, 10, "Font size"}, 10, 40, 5}
 ]
```

[image]

My question(s):

1. How is LabelingSize related to FontSize? and/or ChartSize?
2. "Fig" or "FIG" is rendered quite differently than other labels. What is the shape of the bounding box that determines the final size of the rendered text?
3. How is a ChartSize established? I cannot find an option in the docs, so I am using ImageSize.
4. I still need to print labels radiating outward and I thought that `Style[..]` would be sufficient, but any pointers would be welcome.

I appreciate any help on this post since I have spent some time and I cannot figure it out from the docs. I prefer to use built in functions (if any) but it is not essential. Thanks for reading.

Comment: The interaction of different option settings is often suboptimally documented.
Try LabelingSize -> Full , which at least gets all font size the same.

Comment: @RolfMertig Thanks. It solves pt(4) in my post convincingly. If I had ~8000 functions to document, it wouldn't be an easy task I suppose. it would be pointless to pursue points (1-3) since these behaviors may change in future versions. From the point of view of a company, 'undocumented' assets are disposable assets. If you want to share other insights about labeling behavior as an answer, I will gladly accept it and you can edit my question accordingly to make it more generally useful. Thanks again.